# Matrice recursive relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, recursion

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two non-singular matrices such that $A \neq I$, $B^4 = I$, and $BA^3 = AB$, then what is the least value of $k$ for which $A^k = I$?

> \begin{align}k&=80\end{align}

My attempt:

By taking inverse in given relation,$A^3 = B^{-1}AB$

Since $B^4=I$, $B^{-1}=B^3$. So, $A^3=B^3AB$. How to proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from what you got:
$$
A^3 = B^{-1} A B
$$
Raise to the 3rd power:
$$
A^9 = B^{-1} A^3 B = B^{-2} A B^2
$$
Doing it two more times:
$$
A^{81} = B^{-4} A B^4 = A
$$
Cancelling $A$:
$$
A^{80} = I
$$
I skipped some of the details but I'm sure you can fill the blanks.

Comment: Very nice approach sir. May I know how the idea striked? Was there any inherent pattern in the question itself?

Comment: A nice trick to remember is that $p(B^{-1} A B) = B^{-1} p(A) B$. I learned it in my linear algebra classes and it comes handy some times (p a polynomial).